# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and this is a code for Collision Physics & Rigidbody Movement, but when I save the script unity showed this. Problems are at lines 45 and 50.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
public float moveSpeed;

private Animator anim;
private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

private bool playerMoving;
private Vector2 lastMove;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    playerMoving = false;

    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
    {
        //transform.Translate (new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y); 
        playerMoving = true;
        lastMove = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f );
    }

    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f )
    {
        //transform.Translate (new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
        playerMoving = true;
        lastMove = new Vector2(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }

    If(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > -0.5f)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0f, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    If(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > -0.5f )
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, 0f);
    }

    anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
    anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    anim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", playerMoving);
    anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", lastMove.x);
    anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", lastMove.y);
}
}
```

Comment: You're writing your if-statements with uppercase I, which then makes it a method call. Use `if`, not `If`.

Comment: Note: we don't see line numbers here. Please add comments to the code like "the next line shows the error <details>"

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen ty so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two:

```
If(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > -0.5f)
...
If(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > -0.5f )
```

Are method calls, because you wrote `If` and not `if`.

The C# compiler is case sensitive and the C# keyword for if-statement is `if`, not `If`.

As such the compiler doesn't understand why you followed a method call with a block and not a semicolon:

```
If(...) { ... }
```

Which could just as easily have been this to make it clearer:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test") { ... }
```

So change your `If` statements to `if` and it should work a tad better.